# How can one calculate at surface the electric or magnetic field strength for 50Hz 240VAC wire at 1 meter depth?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-flux, emf, formula-derivation, field-strength

How can one approximately calculate at surface the electric or magnetic field strength for 50Hz 240VAC wire buried at 1 meter soil depth for a given current?

Say in sandy clay soil with no mineral deposits that hopefully does not influence the field strength.

As a reference, electromagnetic field detector instruments typically have the following specifications:

- Magnetic field strength range: 0.01~199.9μT(0.1~1999mG)
- Electric field strength range: 0~1999V/m
- Magnetic field strength resolution: 0.01μT/0.01mG
- Electric field strength resolution: 1V/m
- Magnetic field strength frequency range: 20Hz~300Hz
- Electric field strength frequency range: 20Hz~3500MHz

I'd like to calculate whether these range would suffice.

Comment: Is it one single wire or is it a cable, where the remote fields are much cancelled ?

Comment: Is it one single wire. The CAT4 radio detector in passive mode detects it so the sheath does not seem to be shielded.

Comment: is that `field strength at 1 m depth` or `wire at 1 m depth`?

Comment: With zero current, your magnetic field will be very close to zero.

Comment: @jsotola that's wire at 1 m depth; field strength at surface

Comment: @winny I'd imagine at least 1 amp must flow before anything easily would be detected.

Answer (score 0):

For Biot-Savart: $$l^{}_{cable} >> r$$
This validity is right in stationary regime, well approximated at $$f = 50 Hz$$

So you need to use this formula: $$H(r) = \frac{I}{2\pi r}$$ where I is in Ampère and r in meters

Comment: okay so that's $H(r) = \frac{1}{2\pi} = 159.155mG$ so that should easily be detected if the spec. I've quoted is to be believed. Not sure why tex command does not work with $ like in math.stackexchange